# spark sql unable to find the database and table which it earlier wrote to

Tags: scala, apache-spark, warehouse

There is a spark component creating a sql table out of transformed data. It successfully saves the data into spark-warehouse under the <database_name>.db folder. The component also tries to read from existing table in order to not blindly overwrite. While reading, spark is unable to find any database other than default.

sparkVersion: 2.4

```
val spark: SparkSession = SparkSession.builder().master("local[*]").config("spark.debug.maxToStringFields", 100).config("spark.sql.warehouse.dir", "D:/Demo/spark-warehouse/").getOrCreate()

def saveInitialTable(df:DataFrame) {
  df.createOrReplaceTempView(Constants.tempTable)
  spark.sql("create database " + databaseName)
  spark.sql(
    s""" create table if not exists $databaseName.$tableName
      |using parquet partitioned by (${Constants.partitions.mkString(",")})
      |as select * from ${Constants.tempTable}""".stripMargin)
}

 def deduplication(dataFrame: DataFrame): DataFrame ={

  if(Try(spark.sql("show tables from " + databaseName)).isFailure){
    //something 
   }
 }
```

After saveInitialTable function is performed successfully. In the second run, the deduplication function still is not able to pick up the <database_name>

I am not using hive explicitly anywhere, just spark DataFrames and SQL API.

When I run the repl in the same directory as spark-warehouse, it too gives on default database.

```
scala> spark.sql("show databases").show()
2021-10-07 18:45:57 WARN  ObjectStore:6666 - Version information not found in metastore. 
hive.metastore.schema.verification is not enabled so recording the schema version 1.2.0
2021-10-07 18:45:57 WARN  ObjectStore:568 - Failed to get database default, returning 
NoSuchObjectException
+------------+
|databaseName|
+------------+
|     default|
+------------+
```

Comment: what is the value for the variable databasename and where are you setting or assigning a value?

Comment: You can assume them to be set as global variable, I have also run it on debug, variable assignment is not a problem.